# Conditional statement for move methods in BlueJ Java puzzle

Tags: java, conditional-statements, bluej

I have to complete some methods to move across a room to exit. If you step on each spot, it turns a force field on or off. How would I write a conditional statement for the move method? Mine keeps telling me I can't even when I should be able to make a move.

I understand how to move, but I don't understand how to format the conditional statement to allow me to move past barriers that are off (false) while other barriers are on (true). That is, if the red barriers are on but yellow is off I should be able to move to yellow, but this is not the case as it tells me the path is blocked.

```java
 /*
 * 
 * This class allows a user to walk around in a virtual 3x3 room 
 * and solve a puzzle.
 * 
 * The room has nine locations with the following (x, y) coordinates.
 * 
 *                      (0, 0)  (1, 0)  (2, 0)
 *                      (0, 1)  (1, 1)  (2, 1)
 *                      (0, 2)  (1, 2)  (2, 2)
 *                      
 * The user starts at location (1, 2).  Directly across the room from the 
 * user is a door.  The door may be blocked by 0, 1, or 2 force fields.  
 * The frame of the door identifies which force field is currently blocking 
 * it: a red frame means that only the red force field is on, a yellow frame 
 * means that only the yellow force field is on, an orange frame means that 
 * both force fields are on, and a green frame means that both fields are off. 
 * 
 * Depending where the user steps in the room one of the force fields will 
 * either turn on or off. The goal of the puzzle is to cross the room (i.e., 
 * reach position (1,0)) facing the door with both force fields off (i.e., a 
 * green frame).  
 * 
 * The constructor and the methods of this class are incomplete.  The comments 
 * tell you what is missing.  You do not need to add any fields to this class.  
 * You do not need to change any of the other classes in this project.
 */

public class Puzzle
{

    //Your current xy position in the room
    private int xPosition;
    private int yPosition;

    //Boolean variables that tell you whether or not the red and yellow
    //force fields are currently turned on (true) or off (false).
    private boolean yellowField;
    private boolean redField;

    private View view;

    public Puzzle()
    {

        /*
         * Finish: Initialize xPosition and yPosition to reflect that your 
         * initial position in the puzzle is (1,2) and that both force fields 
         * are initially off.
         */
        xPosition = 1;
        yPosition = 2;
        yellowField = false;
        redField = false;
        view = new View();
        view.display(xPosition, yPosition, yellowField, redField);
    }

    public void moveForward() 
    { 
        /*
         * Finish: Implement this method that moves you forward in the room
         * if there is not a wall blocking you.  Otherwise print a message
         * alerting the user that this move is not permitted now.
         * 
         * If the move is allowed then you should call toggleFields() and
         * view.display(xPosition, yPosition, yellowField, redField) afterward.
         */

     }

    public void moveBackward()
    {
        /*
         * Finish: Implement this method that moves you backward in the room
         * if there is not a wall blocking you.  Otherwise print a message
         * alerting the user that this move is not permitted now.
         * 
         * If the move is allowed then you should call toggleFields() and
         * view.display(xPosition, yPosition, yellowField, redField) afterward.
         */

        if (yellowField)
        {
            if (yellowField == false)
                {
                    yPosition += 1;
                    toggleFields();
                    view.display(xPosition, yPosition, yellowField, redField);
                }
            else
                {
                    System.out.println("Your path is blocked pick another move");
                }
        }
        else
        {
            if (redField == false)
                {
                    yPosition += 1;
                    toggleFields();
                    view.display(xPosition, yPosition, yellowField, redField);
                }
            else
                {
                    System.out.println("Your path is blocked pick another move");
                }
        }
    }

    public void moveRight()
    {

    }

    public void moveLeft()
    {
        /*
         * Finish: Implement this method that moves you to the left in the room
         * if there is not a wall blocking you.  Otherwise print a message
         * alerting the user that this move is not permitted now.
         * 
         * If the move is allowed then you should call toggleFields() and
         * view.display(xPosition, yPosition, yellowField, redField) afterward.
         * 
         */

    }

    private void toggleFields()
    {
        /*
         * Finish: Implement this method that turns a field on or off depending 
         * on where you step.  The following table describes the coordinate system 
         * and the effect of stepping in a particular location.
         * 
         * The x coordinate of a location is its row number, and the y coordinate 
         * is its column number.
         * 
         *     0   1   2  
         *  ------------
         *  0| r   r   r
         *   |
         *  1| r   y   r
         *   |
         *  2| y   y   y
         *  
         *  
         *  By stepping in a location labeled 'r' the red force field will turn 
         *  'on' if it is currently 'off' and 'off' if it is currently turned 'on'.
         *  
         *  By stepping in a location labeled 'y' the yellow force field will turn 
         *  'on' if it is currently 'off' and 'off' if it is currently turned 'on'.
         */
        if(redField)
        {
            if (redField == true)
            {
                redField = false;
            }
            else 
            {
                redField = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (yellowField == true)
            {   
                yellowField = false;
            }
            else
            {
                yellowField = true;
            }
        }
    }  

    public void walkthrough()
    {
        /*
         * Extra Credit:  Provide a sequence of calls to moveForward(), moveLeft(), 
         * moveRight(), and moveBackward() that solves the puzzle.  The puzzle is
         * solved if these moves take the user from location (1, 2) to location (1, 0)
         * facing a green door.
         * 
         */   
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please reformat your question to include proper punctuation. It is very hard to understand even what you are asking. Try to isolate your question and the relevant code instead of pasting the full question and all the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
The mistake of your method is you are not taking note on what coordinates will the yellow or red field will turn on/off. You are just checking if you they are turn on/off. So first you must take note of those different coordinates since as you have said, there are certain coordinates that will make either the yellow/re field turn on/off. Once you know these coordinates you then check if the user is in a yellow/red position, then after that you should check what state is that field is (e.g. if it is currently on, then you turn it off).

> I understand how to move, but I don't understand how to format the 
>   conditional statement to allow me to move past barriers that are off (false) 
>   while other barriers are on (true). That is, if the red barriers are
>   on but yellow is off I should be able to move to yellow, but this is
>   not the case as it tells me the path is blocked.

Base from what you said above I think you misinterpreted the problem. You are assuming that each location has a force field and it depends on the y/r letter on the map, but I think it is not the case. Only the door has a force field and your goal is to get to that location where the door is with all the force fields off. Since if you stick to your understanding and the goal is to take the user from location (1, 2) to location (1, 0) facing a green door (all fields are off) it will be impossible.

This will be the map:

```
               0   1   2
            --------------  
            0| r   r   r  
            1| r   y   r  
            2| y   y   y
```

Then this will be the status:
start in coordinate (1,2) (redField is off, yellowField is off)
move to coordinate (1,1) (redField is off, yellowField is on)
move to coordinate (1,0) (redField is on, yellowField is on)

You are in the goal location but all fields are on, thus you are still not done yet, however in this state you can not move since all fields are on. Making this problem unsolvable if you assume that the algorithm to be done is just like what you said.

From that you can refer to my original answer on how to solve the problem.

**Original Answer:**
First of all I will have these assumptions since your description on how the game works is unclear.

1. The goal of the game is to go to a "certain" place but you have to turn off all the force fields of that location in order to get in.
2. That "certain place" is never declared in the program and there is no method parameter that declares it, thus I am assuming that it is a static variable. So for now the I will use the comment of the walkthrough method and assign the user location to (1, 2) and the "certain" place location to (1, 0)

Given the above assumption here is how you will implement the game.

You have to implement these checks:

1. First you have to check for boundaries.

   ```
   In your case this one:

   (0, 0) (1, 0) (2, 0)

   (0, 1) (1, 1) (2, 1)

   (0, 2) (1, 2) (2, 2)

   Thus your x and y coordinate should not be less than 0 or more than 2
   Check if the red field is on. 
   Check if the yellow field is on.
   Check if you are facing the door and the green frame is on
   ```

Here is the gist:

In beginning of your movement methods (moveLeft, moveRight, moveBackward, moveForward) you have to calculate where to user will go. And from that newly calculated place you have to do the above checking (Check 1 only).

Example:

```
public void moveBackward() {
    int tmpY = yPosition + 1; // Subtract 1 from y position since the user is about to move backward

    // Check # 1
    if (tmpY > 2) { // you only need this check since you know that you are only incrementing yPosition
        System.out.println("Your path is blocked pick another move");
        return;
    }

    // If a valid move but the user did not win
    yPosition = tmpY;
    toggleFields();
    view.display(xPosition, yPosition, yellowField, redField);
}
```

Now you have to implement the remaining checks in your toggleFields method.

`public void toggleFields(){
    /* You can store all the locations of the red and yellow fields in a matrix but for simplicity sake I will just hard code it to the if/else statements. 
     * Also the goal location is hard coded since there is no mention from your post where the goal location is. The goal location is (1.0)
     *     0   1   2  
     *  ------------
     *  0| r   r   r
     *   |
     *  1| r   y   r
     *   |
     *  2| y   y   y
     */
    // Check # 2
    if ((xPosition == 0 && yPosition == 0) ||
        (xPosition == 1 && yPosition == 0) ||
        (xPosition == 2 && yPosition == 0) ||
        (xPosition == 0 && yPosition == 1) ||
        (xPosition == 2 && yPosition == 1) ) {
        if (redField) {
            redField = false;
        } else {
            redField = true;
        }
    }

    // Check # 3
    if ((xPosition == 1 && yPosition == 1) ||
        (xPosition == 0 && yPosition == 2) ||
        (xPosition == 1 && yPosition == 2) ||
        (xPosition == 2 && yPosition == 2) ) {
        if (yellowField) {
            yellowField= false;
        } else {
            yellowField= true;
        }
    }

    // Check # 4
    if (!redField && !yellowField && xPosition == 1 && yPosition == 0) {
        System.out.println("You win");
        return;
    }

}`